# Directus Flow: Run custom function within a Flow

Tags: node.js, function, directus, headless-cms, directus-flows

Good day everyone,

I am using the Docker version of [Directus](https://directus.io).

I have the following Flow:

```
- Cron Job > Read Data > Run Script
```

But I want to "Run Function" instead as "Run script" is limited and cannot "import" nor "require" external libraries on it.

I know that I can run an API Endpoint / Webhook. So basically my question is if that I can create a custom extension with an API endpoint and then run it on the Flow, or if it is possible to "Run function".

What I want to do is to run Puppeteer inside a Flow:

```
- Cron Job > Read Data > Loop through the "read data" returned information and run puppeteer to return information.
```

I hope this question is clear.

Regards.

I tried "Run Script" but for security reasons doesn't allow "import" or "require" external libraries (Puppeteer, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can just send a HTTP request to that custom endpoint I guess?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSV list of trusted Node modules to the `FLOWS_EXEC_ALLOWED_MODULES` env var and restart your container. Now you can import those Node modules.

It's mentioned in the docs: https://docs.directus.io/self-hosted/config-options.html